# Generate all possible combinations of 5 binary numbers so that there sum is less or equal to 3

Tags: algorithm, matlab

How can I generate a matrix in Matlab that has 5 rows and some specific number of columns and the elements may only be binary numbers and the column sum has to be less or equal to 3?

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possibilites without loops:

1. Using strings:

   ```
   D = 5;
   S = 3;
   numbers = str2mat(dec2bin(0:2^D-1))-'0';
   numbers = numbers(sum(numbers,2)<=S,:);
   ```
2. Using combinatorial numbers, one line:

   ```
   numbers = [zeros(1,D); cell2mat(arrayfun(@(s) fliplr(full(sparse((1:nchoosek(D,s)).'*ones(1,s), nchoosek(1:D,s), 1))), 0:S, 'uni', 0).')];
   ```

Answer (score 1):

How about this: The maximum binary number, that you can represent by 5bit is 2^5-1 = 31 and skip through these to find the ones with sum of digits <= 3.
Something like

```
n = 1:1:31;
for ii = 1:length(ii)
    bin = dec2bin(ii)
    digitSum = 0
    for d = 1:length(bin)
        digitSum = digitSum + str2num(bin(d))
    end
    if (digitSum <= 3)
        %store results
    end
end
```

Comment: Note that you will typically want to vectorize this if you use Matlab. See the answer that I based on yours.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Dennis!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vecotorized solution to provide all occurences efficiently:

```
Bstr =dec2bin(1:31); 
Bstr(sum(dec2bin(0:31),2)<=sum('00111'),:)=='1'
```

Inspired by the solution of @pyStarter